# CDN for pixel tracking?

Tags: cdn

I use a CDN to deliver static files, but I'm wondering if it's possible to use one for pixel tracking. What I'm looking for is a normal CDN, except it has access logs with full HTTP headers. I'm guessing the storage costs, etc. would make this infeasible, but maybe there is something I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, though what you can do depends highly on the particular CDN provider.

[Amazon's Cloud Front](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) *does* [allow you to get access logs](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/faqs/#Can_I_get_access_to_request_logs_for_content_delivered_through_CloudFront), which it stores in an S3 bucket, and those would allow you to put your tracking image out on their CDN. I don't think they log the full HTTP header, but you still get quite a bit.